# RESTful application is not working as desired. Throwing null pointer exception

Tags: java, spring, jersey, restful-architecture

I'm trying to configure simple CRUD application as a RESTful configuration. The application is returning null pointer exception instead of XML output. Does it have to anything with being the database connection? I checked the application and it's working normally.

**End Point**

```
package com.naveen.end_point;

import java.util.List;

import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.DELETE;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;

import com.naveen.model.Student;
import com.naveen.service.StudentService;

@Path("/student")
public class StudentRESTfulClient {

    @Autowired
    StudentService studentService;

    public StudentRESTfulClient() {

    }

    @DELETE
    @Path("/delete/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response deleteStudent(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        studentService.removeStudent(id);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/list")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public List<Student> getStudentsList() {
        List<Student> list = studentService.getStudentsList();
        return list;
    }

    @POST
    @Path("/add")
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Response addStudent(Student s) {
        studentService.addStudent(s);
        return Response.ok().build();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/studentsById/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
    public Student getStudentById(@PathParam("id") long id) {
        return studentService.getStudentById(id);
    }

}
```

**Error**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    com.naveen.end_point.StudentRESTfulClient.getStudentsList(StudentRESTfulClient.java:44)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.JavaMethodInvokerFactory$1.invoke(JavaMethodInvokerFactory.java:60)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider$TypeOutInvoker._dispatch(AbstractResourceMethodDispatchProvider.java:185)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.model.method.dispatch.ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.dispatch(ResourceJavaMethodDispatcher.java:75)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.HttpMethodRule.accept(HttpMethodRule.java:288)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.ResourceClassRule.accept(ResourceClassRule.java:108)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RightHandPathRule.accept(RightHandPathRule.java:147)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.uri.rules.RootResourceClassesRule.accept(RootResourceClassesRule.java:84)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1469)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl._handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1400)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1349)
    com.sun.jersey.server.impl.application.WebApplicationImpl.handleRequest(WebApplicationImpl.java:1339)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.WebComponent.service(WebComponent.java:416)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:537)
    com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer.service(ServletContainer.java:699)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:729)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

**Service Implementation**

```
package com.naveen.service;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

import com.naveen.dao.StudentDao;
import com.naveen.model.Student;

@Service
@Transactional
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class StudentServiceImpl implements StudentService {

    @Autowired
    StudentDao studentDao;

    @Override
    public List<Student> getStudentsList() {

        return studentDao.findAll();

    }

    @Override
    public void addStudent(Student s) {
        studentDao.saveStudent(s);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateStudent(Student p) {
        studentDao.updateStudent(p);
    }

    @Override
    public void removeStudent(long id) {
        studentDao.deleteStudent(id);
    }

    @Override
    public Student getStudentById(long id) {
        return studentDao.findOne(id);
    }

}
```

**Web.xml Jersey part**

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.sun.jersey.spi.container.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.naveen</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/restful/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: What is in line 44 of StudentRESTfulClient.java? Is your @Autowired working?

Comment: Show the spring configuration as well

Comment: I'm thinking it's working. How would I test if it's working?

Comment: If the service is null, it obviously is not working

Comment: Well, if your 44th line is `List<Student> list = studentService.getStudentsList();`, then it is not working at all.. try debugging or printing the studentService object before calling any operation on it

Comment: Due to studentService is not found. check with your StudentService class

Comment: i'm not sure but should your client be Spring-managed? you autowire sth via Spring but your client isnt Spring-enabled

Comment: I'm not using Spring RESTful configuration. Trying a simple plain jersey implementation.

Comment: Show us what you have done in StudentService

Comment: I think service is not working, but why? Rest of the application is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Please see the extra code, I have added the service imlementation.

Comment: Is your REST class spring managed? Can you put a @Named annotation and check? Have you wired up your ContextListener in ApplicationListener correctly? more details on configurations please

Comment: No, it's not spring managed. I'm just trying to develop a basic CRUD RESTful client. I'm sorry, but I didn't understand what you mean by Context and Application Listeners.

Comment: annotate your client with `@RestController`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I might be not correct as i don't know much about spring, But to return XML as response , in model i use @XmlRootElement annotation in model class when using Jersey Jax-rx . you can try it. but as i said m not sure it will work or not.

Comment: Hello Subro, I annotated my Model class with that annotation. I think the problem here seems to be the autowire failure to service class.

Answer (score 1):

You are autowiring sth via Spring but you are not using a Spring Controller. Please annotate your class with `@Controller` or `@RestController` and define the REST paths you want. Please have a look at Spring documentation about `Controllers`.

Please check this example [here](https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/) from the official Spring documentation.

Comment: I haven't learned how to develop RESTful web services with Spring framework yet. Is there any way to get it to work like a regular Jersey based RESTful application?

Comment: dont mix technologies. if you want to use jersey, find the equivalent tutorial or go the Spring-official way :)

Comment: Hello Apostolos, I think the studentService is null here. But I need to know why. Please let me know what could be the reason?

Comment: but... i just explained to you why! :) annotate your client with `@Controller` and check again. go the Spring-official way!

Comment: Alright then, I'll try to configure it the Spring way. Do I have to change the web.xml and dependencies?

Comment: it's all in the link i posted. it's very clear and you will understand everything. i propose you start a new project so as not to mess up with a lot of changes. clean new project and step by step reading and configuration will be the best option imho :)

Comment: But I don't want to use spring boot to do it. Could I do it with spring mvc?

Comment: yes, spring boot is just an easier step of configuration. you can find lots of examples with spring mvc and rest controllers, but i see that they use Spring Boot everywhere. even I, using Spring mvc for years, think of changing to Boot too :)

Comment: please also consider accepting an answer, if it helped you fix your problem :)

Comment: @HadrianBlackwater did my answer help you? please accept it so as to consider this question closed. thank you!